proof that ball divergence fully characterize the Borel probability measures on finite dimentional Banach space
The question comes from the proof of Theorem 1 in the paper: Ball Divergence: Nonparametric two sample test.
Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be a finite dimensional Banach space, with $\rho$ being the norm induced metric, and $\mu,v$ be Borel probability measures on it. The support of $\mu$, $S_\mu$, is defined as the set of points such that every of their open neighborhoods has positive measure. (similarly we can define $S_v$).
Denote $f(s,t) = \big[\mu(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))-v(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))\big]^2$, where $\bar B(s,r)$ is the closed ball in $V$ with center $s$ and radius $r\geq 0$.
In the proof of Theorem 1 in the paper, the authers showed that
$$f(s,t) = 0 \mbox{ for }\mu\times\mu{-a.s. }\quad(s,t)\in V\times V\qquad (1)$$
$$f(s,t) = 0 \mbox{ for }v\times v{-a.s. }\quad(s,t)\in V\times V,\qquad (2)$$
where $\mu\times\mu,v\times v$ are the product measures on $V\times V$.
The authers then says that: "we know that no $\mu-$null set is contained in $S_\mu$, therefor $\mu(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))=v(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))$ if $s,t\in S_\mu$."
I tried to prove this claim but don't know how to proceed. First of all, should the claim be "no $\mu-$null open set is contained in $S_\mu$"? Even with this claim, I don't know how to show $\mu(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))=v(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))$ for any $s,t\in S_\mu$.
Any help is appreciated !
Update : I've shown Equations (1) and (2) implies the following results:
1, if $s=t\in S_\mu$ and $\mu(\{s\})>0$, then we have $\mu(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))=v(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))$. This means $\mu$ and $v$ have the same atoms and for any atom $s$ we have $\mu(\{s\}) =v(\{s\})$.
2, $S_\mu = S_v$.
3, if $\mu(\{s\})>0$ and $v\in S_\mu$, then we have $\mu(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))=v(\bar B(s,\rho(s,t)))$.
So the only part remaining is to show the claim for $s,t\in S_\mu$ such that $\mu(\{s\})=0$....which I don't know how to show.

Just as an partial answer: By the definition of the support $S_\mu$ one has, as the authors write also:
\begin{equation}
S_\mu^c = V \setminus S_\mu = \{ x \in V | \exists U \in \mathcal{N}_x \cap \mathcal{O} : \mu(U) = 0  \} = \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{O}, \mu(B) = 0 } B = \bigcup_{B \in (B_n) , \mu(B) = 0} B  
\end{equation}
where $(B_n)$ is some countable basis for the separable space $V$, from which $\mu(S_\mu^c) = 0 $ follows by $\sigma$ (sub) additivity. Now if $A \in \mathcal{O}$ (i.e. open) and $\mu(A) = 0$ then it must necessarily be contained, appearing as one instance of the union on the right hand side of the above equation, i.e. $ A \subset S_\mu^c$ or, $A \cap S_\mu = \emptyset$.
Carrying this argumentation over to $V \times V$, if there is an open $\mu$ zero  set $A$ such that $f|_A \neq 0 $, then we must have $A \cap (S_\mu \times S_\mu) = \emptyset$, i.e. $f|_{S_\mu \times S_\mu} = 0 $.
But for arbitrary $\mu$ zero sets $A$, for this to hold, there must be more restrictions on $\mu$, since in general
\begin{equation}
\mu(A) = 0 \nRightarrow A \cap S_\mu = \emptyset 
\end{equation}
for example for the lebesgue measure (or also a prob. measure like $1/(2\pi)^{n/2}\exp(-|x|^2/2) d^n x $)  one has for any point $x$ that $\mu(\{ x \} ) = 0 $ but still clearly for any open neighborhood/ euclidean ball around x that $\mu(B_r(x)) > 0 $
So I guess maybe one salvation is to simple make the statement weaker to $\mu \times \mu$ a.s. all $(t,s) \in S_\mu \times S_\mu$.
